# Reading an Image file from a mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display an image, but my webpage displays encoding stuff instead. Below is my code:

```
<?php ob_start();?>

// html markups goes here

<?php include 'login.php';
if(isset($_GET['productid'])){
    $productid = $_GET['productid'];

    $sql = "select tyre_image from tyres where product_id = '$productid'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    header("Content-type :image/jpg");
    echo mysql_result($result,0);

}

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

I am using $_GET associative array($_GET['variable']) to get the product ID via a link on another page.

How would I fix this?

Comment: why do you save the images into the DB instead of the path?

Answer (score 3):

I had no idea the `Content-type` header was this picky, but change the spacing around the colon (and also `image/jpg` should be `image/jpeg`):

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

Per the answer below, I agree - this fix assumes that this script is just used for displaying an image in your HTML, ala `<img src="path/to/your/image.php?productid=123" />`.

Further light reading on the `image/jpeg` [MIME type spec here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046).